# Creating a dataset which provides specific regression output

Tags: regression, synthetic-data

I need to create a synthetic dataset with 1000 rows for two variables X and Y. I need the relationship between X and Y to be set up such that when I run a regression model, it provides specific output, e.g. slope of 1.2 (se=0.04) and intercept -0.4 (se=0.07).

For a simple linear model it is easy enough to do this by creating a normally distributed X variable and creating Y and adding noise:

```
Y = rnormal(1.2, 0.04*sqrt(N))*X
```

For this very simple model with one coefficient the output exactly matches the desired slope and se (after iterations).

But for a slope and intercept model I am unable to use a similar technique such as:

```
Y = (rnormal(1.2, 0.04*sqrt(N))*X) + (rnormal(-0.4, 0.07*sqrt(N))
```

The standard errors are always too large. I think this may have something to do with covariance between the errors of the coefficients, but haven't found a solution. I there a way to create such a dataset?